# Why is the Angle different between layout and modelling

Tags: modeling

I have place an object in my scene, and the angle seems different between layout and modelling. I don't know what I have done. I try to reset the camera, also press 5 on number pad but It's looking odd in modelling mode.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Numpad 5 should work, could you please share your file?

Comment: It looks as if one view is in Perspective and one in Orthographic view. As @moonboots says, hit Numpad-5 or the grid icon to the right of the viewport below the camera one to toggle between the two views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Viewport 'View' camera is region-context dependent. Both your views are perspective, but one appears to have a much longer focal-length than the other, tending towards orthographic:

[image]

You can set the 'View' focal-length to your preference for each workspace.

Comment: How on earth this happened I don't know, but that was it, the focal length was different. Kind regards.